# Handoff programming with Safari (iOS 8)

Tags: objective-c, ios8, handoff

I want to open a native app along with the UserInfo(some sort of custom request) when the user clicks a button on my webpage in Safari browser. As per apple documentation, When you want to do Webpage-to-native-app handoff, UserInfo is always nil.

Is there any workaround to achieve this?

Comment: -1 as you have already asked a question about this that has been closed because you couldn' be bothered adding detail to the question or asking an actual question, so again I have voted to close but now as a possible duplicate of [Is it possible to do handoff programming with Safari extensions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209268/is-it-possible-to-do-handoff-programming-with-safari-extensions) Please stop adding a question that is exactly the same as once you have already asked it is pointless and will just get them closed and that will not help you at all

Comment: ok @Popeye, Sorry about that. I have deleted the previous question btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though `userInfo` will always be empty, there might be a workaround. From reading the documentation, it seems that only the domain of `webpageURL` is tested for equality to the domain associated with your App ID. Therefore, if you'd like to pass any extra data along to your app, you might be able to do it by appending a query string or hash fragment to the end of the URL.

E.g., http://example.com/?email=123&level=5 or http://example.com/#email=123&level5